# Upload GCM to Google App Engine without Eclipse

Tags: android, google-app-engine, java

I'm trying to upload the Google Cloud Messaging demo App Engine site to App Engine, but I have a problem with the upload command..

I'm following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading

When I had tried this command:
`appcfg.cmd update C:\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-appengine\WebContent`

I got this error:
`Unable to update app: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.`

I have found some solutions to this error on Eclipse, but I'm not using Eclipse App Engine plugin.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest JDK installed - [JDK downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Set JAVA_HOME environment to the JDK folder.  If you're on windows it's probably something like: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25